# Facebook external login with Angular + .NET Core + Identity Server 4

Tags: angular, facebook, asp.net-core, facebook-graph-api, identityserver4

I'm using Angular (front-end), .NET Core (back-end), and Identity Server 4.

> Angular -> Identity Server 4 (returns access_token) -> Angular (request api with
> token) -> .NET Core

How do I implement facebook external login?

I have seen and search tutorials on the internet but they only implement MVC.

Can anyone recommend me a link tutorial that fit best for what I'm using?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1.**

You can follow this blog to learn [User Authentication and Identity with Angular, Asp.Net Core and IdentityServer](https://fullstackmark.com/post/21/user-authentication-and-identity-with-angular-aspnet-core-and-identityserver). You also can refer the [source code](https://github.com/mmacneil/AngularASPNETCoreOAuth).

**Step 2.**

Read official doc: [Adding Support for External Authentication](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/4_external_authentication.html#adding-support-for-external-authentication)